# What is the consequence of the percent-deprecation of iframe's width attribute?

Tags: css, html, iframe, language-lawyer

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), the `width` attribute of the `iframe` element is defined as follows:

> Indicates the width of the frame **[HTML5]** in CSS pixels, or **[HTML 4.01]** in pixels or as a percentage.

Does that mean that:

1. iframes having a percentage width are no longer officially supported in HTML5 or that
2. CSS should be used for iframe widths instead (e.g. `<iframe style="width: 100%">`)?

Argument in favor of option 1: If they just wanted people to move to CSS, they would have deprecated the width and height attributes altogether, not just one arbitrary subset of allowed values.

Argument in favor of option 2: Using CSS for iframe widths does seem to work on HTML5 pages (which could mean that (a) it's officially supported or (b) that my browser is just being nice to me).

Which one is it? Official sources in answers preferred.

Comment: It means that you should use CSS. Now there are plenty of sources saying CSS is the preferred way to go (and in fact I'm not sure why you are saying CSS "seems" to work), but I can't seem to find any official documents explaining why the `width` and `height` attributes are still there.

Comment: @MrLister: That's exactly the point: It just seems odd to me that "width attribute in percent" was deprecated but "width attribute in pixels" was not. If "just use CSS instead" was the intention, why not deprecate the width and height attributes altogether?

Comment: Then that's what the question should have been.

Comment: @MrLister: I have updated my question. Better now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Percentage dimensions *are* deprecated in favor of CSS, because percentages are relative to something, which is invariably a matter of layout.

Absolute (CSS pixel) dimensions are not, because they represent the intrinsic dimensions of the embedded content. This is the very same reason why the `width` and `height` attributes on the `img` element aren't deprecated either.

[W3C HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element) provides a banner ad example — note the dimensions:

> The `iframe` element supports dimension attributes for cases where the embedded content has specific dimensions (e.g. ad units have well-defined dimensions).
>
> **Code Example:**
>
> Here is an example of a page using an iframe to include advertising from an advertising broker:
>
> ```
> <iframe src="http://ads.example.com/?customerid=923513721&amp;format=banner"
>         width="468" height="60"></iframe>
> ```

Comment: But iframes are used to display HTML documents, which don't have intrinsic dimensions.

Comment: By the way, most of those HTML code examples on the W3C site are not exactly shining examples of best practices. Missing </p> end tags all over the place etc.

Comment: @Mr Lister: So don't specify dimensions for those things. Iframes aren't limited to traditional, free-flow HTML documents - they're used for embedding all sorts of external content all the time. And "missing" </p> end tags may not be best practice but for the sake of brevity and demonstration they are perfectly acceptable. In fact, the spec does this *on purpose* to show that indeed, end tags aren't always required. (I should just write a blog post about this since I keep [bringing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/70311880) it [up](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/71360955).)

Comment: I know, I know. Believe me, I'm well aware of the specs. And I too get annoyed if someone comments "Hey, you forgot the quotes around the attribute" to a post with a perfectly valid HTML source. Like that would fix the OP's problem. Or even when there are _real_ errors in the HTML, and people only comment "You shouldn't use a table here". As if that is more important that the errors!

Comment: But I digress, sorry. I only tried to say that people shouldn't use the code examples on w3.org as examples of how it should be done, what well-written HTML looks like.